# Problems with groovy sql withbatch

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I usually wouldn't post for problems with an API but I'm completely stumped. I'm trying to use groovy's withBatch() method and it is blowing up on me. Here's what I'm trying:

```
connection.withBatch ('insert into SCHEMA.TABLE(VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)') { ps ->
    for(def dom : domain.domainData)
    {
        def values = dom.collect {key, value -> value}
        ps.addBatch(values)
    }
```

And I keep getting this:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   groovy.sql.Sql.withBatch() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String, ...updater.InsertAllService$_updateData_closure1)
>   values: [insert into
>   SCHEMA.TABLE(VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE)
>   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),
>   ...updater.InsertAllService$_updateData_closure1@74eb011d] Possible
>   solutions: withBatch(groovy.lang.Closure), withBatch(int,
>   groovy.lang.Closure), isWithinBatch()

(I had to take out the values and package names for privacy reasons)

I have been tinkering with this all morning trying different things (including the other withBatch methods) and I keep getting this same error. Does anyone see what I'm doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Groovy?  The `withBatch` variant that takes a String and a Closure was only introduced in Groovy 1.8, the "possible solutions" in your error message suggest you're on Groovy 1.7.

Comment: Check that there aren't any earlier versions of the groovy JAR(s) that have got onto your classpath somehow (maybe as a transitive dependency of something else if you're using maven/ivy/`@Grab`)